# Send text to clipboard in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, clipboard, accent-sensitive

I am working with a form that does not allow to type accents, but it does allow to paste text with accent.

How can I send text to the clipboard, then paste the text containing accent into the form?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=options)

driver.get('https://www.website.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, openform))).click()

send accent text to clipboard


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, formfield).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

Comment: So you want to send_keys, highlight ctrl a, copy ctrl c  and then paste ctrl v?

Comment: I want to insert the text to paste with selenium directly to the clipboard

Comment: Why don't u just send the text that u wanna enter to the textbox via ```send_keys```?

Comment: because the text box does not allow accents, but it does allow accented text when pasting it

Comment: You've got an answer below  - but have you tried setting your text via javascript? - using the clipboard is potentially over complicating your soltuon.

Comment: I have not dealt with javascript.  When but the text or I write it, the text box transforms it into capital letters with or without accent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this in python to copy the desired text in clipboard and then pasting it. It is working with python 3.8. You can try it too. if you face any issue then let me know.

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('Text to be copied to the clipboard.')
clipboard_text= pyperclip.paste()
print(clipboard_text)
```

Comment: it doesn't work for selenium headless, it only works for selenium with GUI.